# Visual Studio Converts my picture to a Byte[] when I add it as a Resource to my WP8 App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Whenever I upload an Image to my Windows Phone app (through resource manager) Visual Studio will convert it into a Byte[]

So in short I can no longer use it as an actual image file in my C# code without having to go through the trouble of converting it back again, which I just don't find to be the right solution

Is there any way to add images into resources still being accessible from the code and it NOT being converted to a byte[] in the process ?

(Picture Prof can be submitted when I get home if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Your image will still be somewhere in the project, so you can access it through the path to its location. For example:

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```